# Is there a way to divide the categories by parent, in the article editor?

Tags: wordpress

On my site, there are many categories of topics such as: countries, system, company .. and each category contains a multiple sub-category.
When creating an article, it is difficult to categorize it
Is there a way or code to divide the categories, so that can put each parent with his children  in a widget

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, nor with any plugin I know of. It's certainly possible to accomplish but would require a fair bit of custom coding. What you're trying to do is sorta an edge-case; you're treating top-level categories as a sort of "header" and WordPress assumes each category is, well, a category. Generally, I'd suggest you'd be better off with a custom plugin (ideally) or something built with ACF or similar that introduces custom terms for each requested type of data. However, for the sake of discussion, you'd  have to do something like this:

- Remove the existing category widget from selected post types

  - Hook `admin_head`
  - Use `remove_meta_box` to remove the existing meta box
- Add custom widgets

  - Hook `add_meta_boxes`
  - Grab the available terms for the post type
  - Iterate through the list and generate a "slug" for each top-level term
  - Use `add_meta_box` with your generated details to register a new widget
  - Hook `save_post` (with a bunch of validation) to collate and save

The fun challenge here is that you're forced to work with a pre-existing data structure - WordPress stores categories (and other tags) in a specific way, but you're trying to abstract that out to multiple entry points. This means that on render you have to extract the relevant data from the saved data structure, and on save you have to merge all those entry point submissions back into the expected data structure.

Comment: in ACF , is it possible to convert "select option" data to category ?